# Using Terraform to add Storage Virtual Network Rule

Tags: azure-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way to add a Virtual Network Rule to a storage account like there is with Azure SQL? There is the `azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule` but there does not appear to be an equivalent for storage accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample of [Usage with Network Rules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html#example-usage-with-network-rules), you could refer to it.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "testrg" {
  name     = "resourceGroupName"
  location = "westus"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
    name = "virtnetname"
    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
    name                 = "subnetname"
    resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}"
    address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
    service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql","Microsoft.Storage"]
  }

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "testsa" {
    name = "storageaccountname"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name}"

    location = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.location}"
    account_tier = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"

    network_rules {
        ip_rules = ["127.0.0.1"]
        virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${azurerm_subnet.test.id}"]
    }

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks...I must have been looking at that page too long because I completely missed that.